# How to view possible command line options of LLVM pass loaded using opt tool?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

> How to view possible command line options of LLVM pass loaded using opt tool?

I've registered the following options for my pass:

```
static cl::opt<int>
        ObfProbRate("ipred-prob",
                    cl::desc("Probability [%] each basic blocks will be obfuscated"),
                    cl::value_desc("probability rate"), cl::init(defaultObfRate), cl::Optional);

static cl::opt<int>
        ObfTimes("ipred-times", cl::desc("Times the to loop on a function"),
                 cl::value_desc("number of times"), cl::init(defaultObfTime), cl::Optional);
```

The pass itself runs just fine, and it accepts the command line options via `opt`.

However, I'd like to see the available options. Therefore I issue the following command:

```
opt -load cmake-build-debug/ipred/libIPredOPass.so -ipredO -help
```

Now, instead of available options being displayed, it displays the usual `opt -help` output.

How can I see the command line options specific to my `ModulePass` pass?

I am running LLVM 3.9.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Doesn't that usual `opt -help` output contain your options?

Comment: I cannot see where? Indeed it contains my pass "ipredO" among the many passes available (using -load), but it doesn't show the command line options for the individual passes like mem2reg... How do I see those?